# PHP expanding table with input

Tags: php, html, css

My assignment is to Write a PHP script to display string, values within a table. As the user enters in new information the table would expand to include that information. When I run this script it overwrites the existing information. I can only use PHP. I've seen other examples that use jQuery and JavaScript.

Also the inner borders of the table do not show. If someone could show me how to fix that that would be great. Thanks.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
} 
</style>

<?php
$err = "";
?>
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
        Please enter a name: <input type="text" name="string"><br/>
        Please enter in a amount in $: <input type="text" name="number"><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br/>
        <span><?php echo $err;?></span></br><br/>
</form>
<?php
    echo "<table>";
    $err = "";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["string"]) || empty($_POST["number"]) ) {
            $err = "Please fill both fields.";
        } else {
            $name = $_POST["string"];
            $number = $_POST["number"];
            echo "<tr><td> Salary of $name is <td/><td> $number <td/><tr>";
        }
    }
echo "</table>";
?>

    </br><br/>
    <a href="Assignment5-php.html">Back</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this that are important. First, you should `array` your form inputs and second add `hidden` inputs and loop through the form to store the data for the next addition. No `$_SESSION` required for this solution:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
/* You need to add the borders to the TDs as well */
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
} 
td:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<?php
$err = "";

// I am making this a function, but you can split this into
// separate foreach loops in the two spots
function LoopPost($type = 'form')
    {
        // I've made no allowance for empty values, you can write that part
        if(isset($_POST['number'])) {
                // Loop through the posts to either display form inputs
                // or render the table rows
                foreach($_POST['number'] as $key => $value) {
                        if($type == 'form') { ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="string[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['string'][$key], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="number[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
            <?php           }
                        else { ?>
            <tr>
                <td>Salary of <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['string'][$key], ENT_QUOTES); ?> is</td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php           }
                    }
            }
    }
?>
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <!-- Array these inputs. It will store multiple key/value pairs -->
        Please enter a name: <input type="text" name="string[]"><br/>
        Please enter in a amount in $: <input type="text" name="number[]"><br/>
        <?php LoopPost(); // Default is to render form ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br/>
        <!-- Just a reminder, I've made no validation checks -->
        <span><?php echo $err;?></span></br><br/>
</form>
<table>
<?php
    $err = "";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["string"]) || empty($_POST["number"]) )
            $err = "Please fill both fields.";
        else
            // You can fill this function with any value except false or empty
            // Empty/false will render the form inputs
            LoopPost('table');
    } ?>
</table>
    </br><br/>
    <a href="Assignment5-php.html">Back</a>
</body>
</html>
```